# How to update an Android app programmatically

Tags: android

I have developed an app for Android. When I installed it for first time, the app works. But when I do some changes in source code, we cant install it without deleting it from phone. I want that app should be updated wen I install it for second time. Any solutions?

Note: My app consists of database which I don't want to delete so want to update new app on existing one

Comment: have you tried only to delete the app cache and data from options? what kind of data do you persists? what kind of changes do you do?

Comment: Are you trying to install a debug version over a release version? If so, you can't do that. You can only update a release version with another release version or update a debug version with another debug version.

Comment: what is the error you get when you install it second time?

Comment: thanks for responding.Basically my app consists of database which I don't want to delete when i install it second time.please help me out guys        Note : I want to do this by programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Change your VersionCode in your Android Manifest to subsequent versions

**android:versionCode**

> android:versionCode — An integer value that represents the version of
>   the application code, relative to other versions. The value is an
>   integer so that other applications can programmatically evaluate it,
>   for example to check an upgrade or downgrade relationship. You can set
>   the value to any integer you want, however you should make sure that
>   each successive release of your application uses a greater value. The
>   system does not enforce this behavior, but increasing the value with
>   successive releases is normative. Typically, you would release the
>   first version of your application with versionCode set to 1, then
>   monotonically increase the value with each release, regardless whether
>   the release constitutes a major or minor release. This means that the
>   android:versionCode value does not necessarily have a strong
>   resemblance to the application release version that is visible to the
>   user (see android:versionName, below). Applications and publishing
>   services should not display this version value to users.

See this http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html

Comment: This isn't necessary unless using Google Play to update the apk.

Answer (score 1):

How you are installing the application if by connecting usb you are trying so the new application will install and you can uninstall the first application and install the updated one so the new application will run perfectly.

Comment: doing that will wipe my data which i dont want .

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have compiled your second version you want to replace the old one... 
I don't know what are you using to program for android, but if you use eclipse sdk that is done automatically..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably because of your keystore with that you export your application. If you export your app with the default Android keystore, and then if you change the app on another PC and export it again with the default keystore on that other PC and install it on the same device, the Android will see that you have 2 same apps but with different keystores. That's why you need to first unistall the app and install it again.

It doesnt matter if you use the defualt Android keystore on both PC-s. They still aren't the same keystore.

One solution is that you create a keystore eg. ProjectKeystore and you create a folder keystore in your project. Put the keystore in that folder, and maybe put a file with the keystore username and pass. With that you can use the same keystore when you export your app on any PC.

Comment: Can you please tell how to create keystore

Comment: Right click on your project -> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application. On the 2nd window there, you will find a radio button. Click on create new keystore. Input all the data and there it is. Now you can put it in a folder in your project. Now when you go and export the application you use that key that you created.

Answer (score 0):

But if you change version code then you will be prompted with this error. So Try looking for keystore
Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
ExpenseTracker] You must perform a full uninstall of the application.

**WARNING:** This will remove the application data!
ExpenseTracker] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.spundhan.expensetracker' in a shell.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems trying to install my apps on occasion.  To solve the problem I went to the app management screen and told the program to stop running then my update installed properly.  I think it has something to do with the way android handles the program lifespan.  When you exit a program it doesn't always stop running.  If there is an error in something then android can have a problem closing the program before it can update it.